# How to manage several files in bundle in Xcode5?

Tags: xcode5

### Context

For testing purposes I use testing scenario contained in **XML** files. Then to access these files in simulator I must add them in **Copy Bundles Resources**.
For App Store distribution I have to remove these files in **Copy Bundles Resources**as there are no longer needed.

This is a fastidious and error prone manipulation. Furthermore when their number becomes important it's a real nightmare to enabling/disabling them.

### Question

So, what is the best way to handle such situation ?

- is there a way to group files in order to easily manage them ?
- do I have to create a specific target for these testing purposes ?
- ...

Comment: Today I tried to used a specific target only for test purposes. This target have all the files from the release version plus the XML files. Furthermore with Xcode5 assets is easy to customize icons and   others pictures for this target. And I noticed this target can have it's own prefix file !

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to deal with a similar situation I kept all the test data files in a subfolder within the project folder. In Xcode I added that as a folder reference, which causes it to always include whatever files are in that folder. For my AppStore-Release configuration I have a build step script which deletes all the files in that test data folder. When my release is done I revert just that folder in source control, which brings the test data files back. There is bound to be a better way to do this, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not have this kind of idea !
I think you can improve your method by storing your files in a storage folder and _copying_ it's content to the test data folder when release is done.

By doing it you don't have to play with source control : storage folder is versioned and test data folder not.

Comment: For small data files that would work quite well. In the app we are using this the 'data' is actually a couple hundred MB of images, and I was specifically trying to avoid copying that much data because of the time it could take on each test run.

Comment: Ok, I understand. And by creating _links_ (aliases) to the images on instead of copying images ?